# punctuation when a quoted question is followed by a reference

Tags: punctuation, question-mark, reference

In my Closing Argument (for an administrative-type hearing), I invented a concise way of referring to page numbers in the Parent exhibit book, for example:

> There was no follow-up to R’s June 22 suggestion to meet in September (Q 202-203).

(Note there is no confusion between parent exhibits and respondent (school) exhibits because the respondent exhibits don't use letters, only numbers.)

Now for my question.  Is the following punctuated correctly?

> The parent responded on 10/13 to request clarification: "Bla-bla-bla.  What sorts of evaluations do you have in mind?” (Q 224)  The parent further expressed a preference for avoiding November due to the father’s work obligations (Q 224-225).

Would it be better to put a period after the reference to Q 224?

> The parent responded on 10/13 to request clarification: "Bla-bla-bla.  What sorts of evaluations do you have in mind?” (Q 224).  The parent further expressed a preference for avoiding November due to the father’s work obligations (Q 224-225).

Comment: @RichardKayser - But I thought references were supposed to look like this: An earlier researcher found that "scientific observation" (J Blow, 1962).

Comment: I'm not aware of a standard way of doing it. Seems like a style manual issue. The only other thought I have would be to add a footnote (for example) the first time you have a reference, to indicate what it is/means. When will you be making your closing argument? Soon, right?

Comment: @RichardKayser - I explained how I'm doing my references in general in order to try to prevent people from getting off track.  Actually, the hearing officer will be fine with the form "Q 224" because that's how I referred to pages in my exhibit book during the hearing.  The question was simply about the period.  But your comment got me confused, because I was so confident that this is reasonable: *An earlier researcher found that "scientific observation" (J Blow, 1962).*  Now I'm wondering if I have to go back and learn how to make references from scratch.

Comment: Sorry. Just trying to help.

Comment: @RichardKayser -  And I appreciate the moral support!  But now I'm a bit confused -- was your comment based on your own experience with citing references in the text?  If not, maybe I should ignore that particular comment?

Comment: Yes. It was based on my experience. But  again, I am not aware of a standard way of doing it. It seems like a style manual issue. Take my comments for what their worth. You know what you're doing. The main point is clarity.

Comment: @RichardKayser  - Thanks.  Okay, based on your experience, do you see a problem with my basic approach?  E.g.: An earlier researcher found that "scientific observation" (J Blow, 1962).

Comment: Gee, maybe I should have posted this question on Academia.  See http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/79758/how-to-add-a-citation-to-a-sentence-that-has-parentheses-at-the-end

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I broke the quote up into two parts:

> The parent responded on 10/13 to request clarification: "Bla-bla-bla. What sorts of evaluations do you have in mind?” (Q 224).
>
> The parent further expressed a preference for avoiding November due to the father’s work obligations (Q 224-225).

The quote ending in a question was actually quite long so I decided it was time to begin a new paragraph.  Side benefit, I was able to put in a period after the reference.